# react functional component with ag grid cannot call parent function via context

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid-react and ag-grid-community version 22.1.1. My app is written using functional components and hooks. I have a cellrenderer component that is attempting to call a handler within the parent component using the example found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/). Is this a bug in ag-grid? I have been working on this application for over a year as I learn React, and this is my last major blocker so any help or a place to go to get that help would be greatly appreciated.

**Cell Renderer Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '../../button/button';

const RowButtonRenderer = props => {
    const editClickHandler = (props) => {
        let d = props.data;
        console.log(d);
        props.context.foo({d});
        //props.editClicked(props);
    }

    const deleteClickHandler = (props) => {
        props.deleteClicked(props);
    }

    return (<span>
        <Button classname={'rowbuttons'} onClick={() => { editClickHandler(props) }} caption={'Edit'} />&nbsp;
        <Button classname={'rowbuttons'} onClick={() => { deleteClickHandler(props) }} caption={'Delete'} />
    </span>);
};

export default RowButtonRenderer;
```

**Parent Component**

```
function Checking() {
  function foo(props) {
    let toggle = displayModal
    setNewData(props);
    setModalDisplay(!toggle);
  }

  const context = {componentParent: (props) => foo(props)};

  const gridOptions = (params) => {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
      return { background: "#ACC0C6" };
    }
  };

  const frameworkComponents = {
    rowButtonRenderer: RowButtonRenderer,
  };

.
.
.

return (
    <>
          <AgGridReact
            getRowStyle={gridOptions}
            frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
            context = {context}
            columnDefs={columnDefinitions}
            rowData={rowData}
            headerHeight="50"
            rowClass="gridFont"
          ></AgGridReact>
    </>
  );
}
```

When clicking the edit button on a row, the debugger says that there is a function.

[image]

This error is received though:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the [`context`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context/) object in this code section:

```js
const context = {componentParent: (props) => foo(props)};

...

<AgGridReact
  context={context}
  {...}
></AgGridReact>
```

And in your cell renderer you call this

```js
props.context.foo({d});
```

While it should be this

```js
props.context.componentParent({d});
```

Also you can assign your callback directly since it receives the same parameter and returns the same result (if any)

```js
function foo(props) {
  let toggle = displayModal
  setNewData(props);
  setModalDisplay(!toggle);
}
const context = {componentParent: foo};
```

You can also use this shorthand syntax from ES6 when assigning object property

```js
function componentParent(props) {
  let toggle = displayModal
  setNewData(props);
  setModalDisplay(!toggle);
}
const context = {componentParent};
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64110983/react-functional-component-with-ag-grid-cannot-call-parent-function-via-context/64113150#64113150]

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I was stumped on this for a while.