# child calling parent function not working properly react

Tags: reactjs, state

suppose i have a product data for sales which i put in a state

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

 products= {
    'product_id':'1',
    'total':'100'
    }
setProducts(products)
```

i send this data to a view products component

```
<SalesViewProducts
            products={products}
            >
</SalesViewProducts>
```

where the view products, SalesViewProducts, component looks something like

```
const SalesViewProducts = (props) => {
  const dispatch = new useDispatch();
  const [inventoryData, setInventoryData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = useState();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    // var total = 0;
    // selectedProducts.forEach(element => {
    //   total+=element.total
    // });
    // props.calculateTotal(total)
  });

  const addProducts = (data) => {
    console.log(props.products);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        size="lg"
        onClick={() => console.log(props.products)}
        // or
        onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
        style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "1rem" }}
      >
        ADD PRODUCTS
      </Button>
      <Table striped bordered hover variant="light">

      </Table>

      <InventoryModal
        modalShow={show}
        modalSetShow={setShow}
        addProducts={addProducts}
      ></InventoryModal>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SalesViewProducts;
```

emphasizing on the button "ADD PRODUCTS", when the onclick function of that button is just console.log(props.products), i get the data just fine from the props.

my issue now comes is this button is actually supposed to open a modal, in which that modal InventoryModal has a whole table of products in inventory and a button that calls a function in the SalesViewProducts component.

```
const InventoryModal = (props) => {
  const dispatch = new useDispatch();

  const gridRef = useRef();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(props.modalShow);
  const handleClose = () => props.modalSetShow(false);

  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: "id", width: 100, headerName: "ID" },
    {
      field: "product_name",
      width: 244,
      headerName: "Name",
      wrapText: true,
      autoHeight: true,
    },
    { field: "product_price", width: 110, headerName: "Price" },
    { field: "in_stock", width: 110, headerName: "Stock" },

    {
      field: "action",
      cellRenderer: (params) => (
        <strong>
          <Button
            variant="success"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => {
              // console.log(params.data.product_name)
              var data = {
                product_id: params.data.id,
                quantity: 1,
                price: 0,
                total: 0,
                name: params.data.product_name,
              };
              props.addProducts(data);
            }}
          >
            Add
          </Button>
        </strong>
      ),
      cellRendererParams: {
        clicked: function (field) {
          alert(`${field} was clicked`);
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllInventoryAction())
      .unwrap()
      .then((data) => {
        setRowData(data.inventoryData);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <Modal show={props.modalShow} onHide={handleClose} size="lg">
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Select Products</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 650, width: "100%" }}>
          <AgGridReact
            ref={gridRef}
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            pagination={true}
            // rowHeight={100}
          ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};
export default InventoryModal;
```

now when i click the add button in the inventory modal, supposedly its supposed to call the parents addProducts function which console.log(props.products). but the result of calling this function is [], why is this so? wheh i call the addProducts function from within the component everything works fine, but when i call the addproducts function from the child component everything goes wrong.

Comment: this seems to be happening because the add button is a part of aggrid, when i move the button out of aggrid with the same functions, everything works fine. why does it not work when its in aggrid?

Comment: can you add a link to codesandbox with your code?

Answer (score -1):

ive solved this problem after realizing the issue was with aggridreact. i had to pass my function to context and then call it through context for it to work. im referencing this stackoverflow question that helped me

[react functional component with ag grid cannot call parent function via context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110983/react-functional-component-with-ag-grid-cannot-call-parent-function-via-context)

```
<AgGridReact
    ref={gridRef}
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        pagination={true}
        context={props}
        // rowHeight={100}

        >
    </AgGridReact>

 setColumn([
        { field: 'id', width: 100, headerName:"ID"},
        { field: 'product_name',width:244, headerName: 'Name',wrapText: true, autoHeight: true,    },
        { field: 'product_price',width:110, headerName: 'Price' },
        { field: 'in_stock',width:110, headerName: 'Stock' },
      
        { field: 'action',
        cellRenderer: (params) => (
            <strong>
              <Button
                variant="success"
                size="sm"
                onClick={()=>{
                  params.context.products()
                 
                }}
              >
                Add
              </Button>
            </strong>
          ),
         },
      
      ])
```